# Electrical help

Tags: electrical

If my lights and plugs are on a 20 amp breaker , which equals out to around 2400 watts .. and I want to pull 2000 watts from a single room . Do I need to install a extra 20 amp breaker dedicated to just that room ? Or can I upgrade my 20 amp (lights and plugs ) to a 40 amp . Sorry I don’t know much on electrical .

Comment: Generally the former, but sometimes the details matter, such as if you're using a device that requires a dedicated circuit (and 2000W is high enough that that's pretty likely).  What exactly are you planning on plugging in that draws 2000W?

Comment: What are you trying to *do* here that makes you want to pull 2kW in a single room?

Comment: I’m setting up a hobby style grow  . With 3 lights ... in which 2 of the lights draw 720 watts(each)  (if ran on 100%) . And 1 draws 420 watts . The whole room with everything will be pulling around 2000 watts-2200 watts  . It’s a very small set up ... there all on 120 outlets .  I was just curious on what needed to be done .  I’m gonna hire an electrician . 100 percent legal . I’m In California , and I’m tired of paying these insane taxes at the dispensaries . Sorry if this offends anyone .

Comment: At the Federal level, I am Tier 1 offended.  However at the state level, I abide :)  Meanwhile, the light really draws a wattage of *420*.... somebody was having fun with that!

Comment: And I thought it was going to be Bitcoin miners.

Comment: When it comes to lighting, it pays to look at LEDs. I don't know if that's an option for your intended usage though.

Comment: I’m using LEDs , they’re just really advanced and strong LEDs .. 900$ a light lol .

Comment: Lol yeah I thought the same thing with the 420 watt model lol .. they were definetely having fun with that one .

Comment: That's a **lot** of light. I realize that growing things requires more intense light than reading a book. But for comparison, a building I go to often has 36 lights @ 35W each (previously bigger LEDs, previous to that fluorescent) = 1,260W - to light up a 3,800 square foot room with tall ceilings - and it is plenty of light to read by. So 50% more light than that in one presumably **much smaller room** is a **LOT** of light.

Answer (score 1):

You can not just upgrade to a larger breaker the existing breaker should be connected to 12 awg wires. Lights are considered continuous so we calculate them at 125%, this limits the load to 80% as is required for continue loads since you are close what are the other loads non continuous loads only need to be calculated at 100% if you go over 20 amps a second circuit will be required. Continuous is defined as 3 hours or more.

Comment: So basically I need to install an additional 40 amp circuit breaker or dual 20s .. dedicated to just the grow? With its own 120 receptacles coming off that breaker ?   to be extra safe that I’m not drawing close to the max of a 20 amp .

Comment: At 1860 watts you only need one more 20A circuit for the loads you quoted to remain just under 80%, but if you have any inkling that you may expand then it would be worth considering using 12/3 cable instead of 12/2 to double your capacity with a multiwire branch circuit that shares the neutral.

Comment: Will if you have a double pole breaker that is 2 legs at 120v we do not consider it 40 amps a multi wire branch circuit can share a neutral this requires a handle tied pair of breakers or a double pole so they are not on the same leg. The small double breakers called tandem , double stuff, cheaters require there own cable because they are on the same leg. (Think odd or even full sized breaker positions it takes an odd and an even to share a neutral. We don’t add breaker amperage for the load on the system we add the load on the circuit and the appropriate safety practice +25% normally

Answer (score 1):

### Find out what is already on the circuit.

That means turning the breaker off, and checking every single outlet and light in the house to see what has gone dead.

I actually like to label the outlets to indicate which breaker they are on.

### Now, total up all the loads on the circuit.

Now that you know which outlets are in-use, you can figure out what the things plugged into them actually use.  All will have a nameplate or sticker stating the amps or watts or VA.  (divide watts or VA by 120 to get amps).

You might find something pleasant: that other than cell phone chargers and desk lights, nothing is on the circuit except your lights.  That would be satisfactory.

### Now, *provision* the loads.

We use that word a bit differently.

Suppose you have a load that runs continuously.  You need some safety margin, and that's defined by Code to be +25%.   So a 10-amp light needs a 25% (2.5A) margin.  So you must *provision* 12.5A for the 10A light.

For non-continuous loads (that run <3 hours at a time), you simply use its amp value straight, so a 1A razor, you provision 1A.

If two things will never be run at the same time (humidifier and dehumidifier), you only need to add the largest one.

Total up the provisioned number.  That must be less than breaker trip.

Example

```
  Light                   4A x 125%  = 5A
  Laser printer           8A         = 8A
  Razor                   1A         = 1A 
  Total -----------------------       14A
```

If the entire circuit was grow lights, your maximum is 16A (x125% = 20A).  So 1920 watts.

Comment: Awesome Harper . Thank you for that breakdown . I’m Starting to understand it much better . I will definetely check the breaker box and do some tests , but I do believe all 3 rooms “ lights and plugs “ in this house are under that (one) 20 amp circuit . But I could be wrong .

Comment: This is a good explanation most don’t understand the code and do all of nothing for 80%